# How can an answer be down-voted two seconds after posting?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I posted this answer a few minutes ago:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25529458/4323

Something interesting was that as soon as I clicked Post Your Answer, my answer was indeed posted, but within two seconds had received one down-vote.  Given that down-voting can only be done by first loading an answer (and not from the front page AFAIK), this seems odd.  Is there an API that allows down-voting?  Is there any known phenomenon or past occurrence like this on Stack Overflow with bots or so?

An up-vote came soon after that, followed by another down-vote.  I'm not asking why my question was down-voted, I'm asking how it can be down-voted two seconds after I posted it.  Surely no one was able to evaluate it so quickly.

Comment: There is a [write API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write) that votes can be cast from. And obviously, someone could monitor the web socket notification for a new answer and quickly take action.

Comment: I don't think you should assume bots or API calls are the culprits here -- sometimes one can be "at the right place at the right time", so to speak, and in position to act on answers right when they are posted. It *may* also come from so-called "defensive downvotes" from other answerers, and in that case they won't even read your answer before downvoting it.

Comment: @StevenV: thanks for the link.  It isn't clear from my reading of it that the API can down-vote, more like post comments and perhaps answers?  It says activity from the API is visibly tagged as such, and the down-vote on my question is not....

Comment: [Downvoting is an API method](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/downvote-answer). But the 'tagging' happens at the database level, so they can tell which app is doing what. The UI hint only existed for comments, I think that has been since removed.

Comment: Maybe someone accidentally clicked the down-vote button and the "up-vote" was really an "un-down-vote" to correct the mistake?  Can mods or someone check if they were from the same user?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When someone is reading the question, they will receive a notification of new answers.
Someone could have clicked this notification to load the new answer (Which really doesn't take any time), (optionally) skim the answer, and vote on it.

Not all votes are justifiable, nor does everyone read the answer properly before voting.

As  [@Frédéric Hamidi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/464709/fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric-hamidi) suggested, the vote could very well have been from another answerer, as a sort of aggressive "tactical voting".

Basically, someone saw your answer, and quickly downvoted it.

Case in point:
The first upvote on this answer arrived within 5-ish seconds <sub>(I guess)</sub> of me posting it. That's not enough time to read the complete answer.

Comment: I did not upvote (yet :p) but I sure could read the original version of your answer under five seconds.

Comment: Do you think it is reasonable that someone got the notification, skimmed my answer, and clicked down-vote, then their vote got to the server and back to me before I even blinked?  It was seriously so unbelievably fast that it's hard to imagine.  And I'm across the world--the one-way latency between me and Stack Exchange is over 130 ms, meaning it probably takes about one second just for the computers to make the transaction happen even if the Stack Exchange software takes zero time.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi But could you read the SO answer in question in that time?  Code often takes more time to digest than English.

Comment: @JohnZwinck It's entirely reasonable.  It's unlikely, sure, which is why it doesn't happen a *ton*, but for it to happen every now and again is entirely expected.  Were there a lot of people using bots to downvote every answer you *would* see this all the time.  The fact that it's rare is evidence *supporting* the fact that it's genuine.

Comment: @Servy, not that one, no. As you say, parsing and validating code requires a context switch (that can take some time depending on the language used). I usually parse English much faster.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Computers are faster than you might think. Anyone can click the "new answer" notification and downvote button without (really) reading the answer. Also, FrédéricHamidi: Fast reader :-)

Comment: @Cerbrus: I know exactly how fast computers are.  It's my job.  :)  That's why I know that there was almost zero time for a human to interpret what I posted, because of the network delays on the minimum of four transactions (me post in Asia -> server in US -> downvoter -> server -> me).  The network latencies alone eat 300 ms at least.

Comment: Then, like I said on Servy's answer: _"Then the person that downvoted you obviously didn't read your answer."_

Comment: @JohnZwinck And how confident are you in your internal clock in saying that there was *exactly* 2000 milliseconds before you saw the downvote?  Could it in fact have been three seconds, instead of two, or even 2,500 ms, or possibly even more than 3 seconds in total?  We're talking about fairly short periods of time, and humans are notoriously poor at estimating times with that level of precision.

Comment: To put @Servy's comment into perspective: the fastest *I've* ever downvoted an answer is about 10 seconds after it was posted. The fastest I've closed a question is 14 seconds. I've taken even longer to delete a post. But I know I'm not the most efficient moderator around, so there's that...

Comment: @BoltClock It's worth noting that both closing and deleting are actions that require a lot more clicks than downvoting, as well as more page loads, server round trips, etc.  It makes sense for them to be longer.  The questions pages are also much more aggressivly cached than answers on a question are, so you're far more likely to not be shown a question at all for a few minutes after it is posted, even if you're looking for new questions, and that doesn't happen with answers (either not as much, or not at all, not sure which).

Answer (score 8):

When throwing a quick glance at the answer, the thing that jumped out immediately for me was the use of `$()` and `printf` in the code. From these two observations (which took very little time) the main point of the answer is clear, even without looking at the details or reading the explanatory text.

Now assume someone looked at the question, though about it, and came to the conclusion that extra indirection with `echo`/`printf` was a bad idea and could never work (quoting problems/...). That's not far fetched since lots of people are likely looking at the question and try to come up with an answer.

Now the "new answer" notification pops up, your answer loads, and it's obvious from the first look that you use exactly that technique that the person already decided was a bad idea. It does not take long to downvote an answer in this case.

Answer (score 7):

New answers to a post are loaded on the page almost instantly through the use of JavaScript and various asynchronous querying technologies, allowing users to see your post almost as soon as you post it.  Some users may take very little time to be able to determine whether or not an answer is valid and vote accordingly.

The comments on your answer even inform you of what problems the readers of your answer have with it.

Comment: The first downvote came much faster than any human could have evaluated the problem with my answer.  I admit the answer isn't great, but it isn't something you can decide within one second of reading.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Then the person that downvoted you obviously didn't read your answer. There's not much you can do about that.

Comment: @JohnZwinck What makes you so sure?  After all the reader only needs to find one problem with the answer to determine that it's flawed, they don't need to read and understand the entirety of it to know that it won't work.